# Puppeteer - Is there a way to pass a function as a parameter to a function that loaded via exposeFunction?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, evaluate

I have a node js project that uses puppeteer, and I would like to use the library async-wait-until within the page context.
This library receives a function as a parameter, tries running it until it returns a truthy value or timeout passes.

The issue is that I get the following error:
Error: predicate is not a function
having predicate the name of the variable that holds the function.

Some code:
This is where I launch the pages - where I expose the function:

```
const waitUntil = require('async-wait-until');
// const waitUntil = require('./node_modules/async-wait-until/src/waitUntil.js');
await page.exposeFunction('waitUntil', waitUntil);
```

Here I am trying to run the function

```
                try {
                    await waitUntil(() => {
                        //Code should come here
                        return false;
                    }, 25000, 1000);
                    console.log('Element Is Ready');
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log('CATCH');
                    console.log(e.toString());
                }
```

And here is the internal js file of the exported function waitUntil:

```
var DEFAULT_INTERVAL = 50;
var DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 5000;


/**
 * Waits for predicate to be truthy and resolves a Promise
 *
 * @param  predicate  Function  Predicate that checks the condition
 * @param  timeout  Number  Maximum wait interval, 5000ms by default
 * @param  interval  Number  Wait interval, 50ms by default
 * @return  Promise  Promise to return a callback result
 */
module.exports = function waitUntil(
  predicate,
  timeout,
  interval
) {
  var timerInterval = interval || DEFAULT_INTERVAL;
  var timerTimeout = timeout || DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;

  return new Promise(function promiseCallback(resolve, reject) {
    var timer;
    var timeoutTimer;
    var clearTimers;
    var doStep;

    clearTimers = function clearWaitTimers() {
      clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
      clearInterval(timer);
    };

    doStep = function doTimerStep() {
      var result;

      try {
        console.log('running predicate function');
        console.log(predicate);
        console.log(timeout);
        console.log(interval);
        result = predicate();
        console.log('ran predicate function');
        if (result) {
          clearTimers();
          resolve(result);
        } else {
          timer = setTimeout(doStep, timerInterval);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        clearTimers();
        reject(e);
      }
    };

    timer = setTimeout(doStep, timerInterval);
    timeoutTimer = setTimeout(function onTimeout() {
      clearTimers();
      reject(new Error('Timed out after waiting for ' + timerTimeout + 'ms'));
    }, timerTimeout);
  });
};
```

When running the code, the prints I get are:
null
25000
1000

Meaning predicate (the function that is being sent) is being recognized as null.
Tried all the different ways (saving it as a function/function expression/anonymous function, with without async), nothing works.

When sending a string instead of the function, the prints do print the string itself, and not null.

Is there something I am doing wrong?
Is there a way to bypass it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems, exposed functions, as well as evaluated functions, can only use serializable arguments, so functions cannot be transferred between Node.js and browser contexts as parameters. Maybe you can try a wrapper and a dictionary of functions, so you can transfer function names as strings:

```js
const waitUntil = require('async-wait-until');

const functions = {
  foo() {
    //Code should come here
     return false;
  },
  bar() {
    //Code should come here
     return false;
  },
};

await page.exposeFunction('waitUntil', async (functionName, param1, param2) => {
  waitUntil(functions[functionName], param1, param2);
});

await page.evaluate(() => {
    await window.waitUntil('foo', 25000, 1000);
});
```